# PocketBase filter data by with multiple relation set

Tags: database, dart, pocketbase

i have a collection where the field "users" contains the id's of two users.

how can i search for this dataset where this both user id's are.

[image]

i tried

```
users = ["28gjcow5t1mkn7q", "frvl86sutarujot"]
```

still don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had asked the same question on twitter and received an answer from [@pocketbase](https://twitter.com/pocketbase):

1. Use the "?" ("at least one of") operators, eg.:
   `http://users.id ?= "${userId}"`
2. Use the "~" contain/like operator against the serialized value:
   `users ~ "${userId}"`

the secord option solved my problem ❤️

Answer (score 0):

This is a relation, so there must be a collection that allows you multiple, non unique results, so this table you are looking at to, is the the dataset, you can query the whole dataset on script with

```
// you can also fetch all records at once via getFullList
const records = await pb.collection('tlds').getFullList(200 /* batch size */, {
    sort: '-created',
});
```

I sugest you to look into: [js-sdk/pocketbase](https://github.com/pocketbase/js-sdk) on github.

Comment: sure, but mobile apps should save so much mobile data as possible. if i have to call all data every time this will cost much.

Comment: oh! maybe I learned something new, I will take a look! thanks